# ACF relationship field search include custom fields

Tags: wordpress, search, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the code below to modify the acf/fields/relationship/result in order to include extra field data to the list. However, this data is not searchable if I use the relationship field's search feature.
Can anyone come up with a way I can extend the search function to include this data? I understand I have to use acf/fields/relationship/query to do this, but I do not know how.

Here is the code that adds the relevant data to the list:

```
function id_relationship_result( $title, $post, $field, $post_id ) {
  // load a custom field from this $object and show it in the $result
  $city = get_field('city', $post->ID);
  $state = get_field('state', $post->ID);

  // append to title
  $title_new = $state . ', ' . $city . ' ' . $title;

  // return
  return $title_new;
}
```

Any help is appreciated....

Answer (score 2):

You're not too far off here - you just need to use a different ACF hook. To modify the title on return, you have to use the ACF acf/fields/relationship/result hook - which is explained here - http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-fields-relationship-result/

So, in your case here, you could add the following to your functions.php file

```
add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/result/name=your_relationship_field_name', 'id_relationship_result', 10, 4);
function id_relationship_result($title, $post, $field, $post_id){
    // load a custom field from this $object and show it in the $result
    $city = get_field('city', $post->ID);
    $state = get_field('state', $post->ID);

    // append to title
    $title = $state . ', ' . $city . ' ' . $title;


    // return
    return $title;
}
```

That will hopefully allow your title to list the data you need and allow for easier filtering

Comment: I can add the data just fine using the filter you mention. My problem is that the extra info (state and city fields) are not searchable...

Comment: Yes, you're right. The search query is only checking against the post title. So what is required is to add some custom filters to the WP Query object. This subject has been covered in this article here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178574/acf-relationship-field-search-filtering. It may be able to help you out